# Subsetting columns of dataframe with grepl not working

Tags: r

A bit embarrassed to be posting this. Must be something trivial I am missing ....

I am trying to subset a dataframe (tmp) to exclude the column 'Tumor_Sample_Barcode'.
For some reason it is not working

```
tmp=tmp [,!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp))]
typeof (tmp)
>> [1] "logical"
```

At the same time running the same code on a similar dataframe works just fine

```
dta=dta[,!grepl("Tumor",names(dta))]
typeof (dta)
>> [1] "list"
is.data.frame (dta)
>> [1] TRUE
```

I cannot understand what is wrong with the tmp dataframe that subsetting isn't working.
Below is some output describing the tmp dataframe

```
dput(names (tmp))

c("Tumor_Sample_Barcode", "B2M_NA", "B2M_MUTATION", "B2M_Synon", 
"B2M_TRUNC", "BCL2_NA", "BCL2_MUTATION", "BCL2_Synon", "BCL2_TRUNC", 
"BTG2_NA", "BTG2_MUTATION", "BTG2_Synon", "BTG2_TRUNC", "CARD11_MUTATION", 
"CARD11_Synon", "CARD11_TRUNC", "CCND3_NA", "CCND3_MUTATION", 
"CCND3_Synon", "CCND3_TRUNC", "CD58_NA", "CD58_MUTATION", "CD58_Synon", 
"CD58_TRUNC", "CD79B_NA", "CD79B_MUTATION", "CD79B_Synon", "CD79B_TRUNC", 
"CIITA_NA", "CIITA_MUTATION", "CIITA_Synon", "CIITA_TRUNC", "CREBBP_NA", 
"CREBBP_MUTATION", "CREBBP_Synon", "CREBBP_TRUNC", "EP300_NA", 
"EP300_MUTATION", "EP300_Synon", "EP300_TRUNC", "EZH2_NA", "EZH2_MUTATION", 
"EZH2_Synon", "EZH2_TRUNC", "FOXO1_NA", "FOXO1_MUTATION", "FOXO1_Synon", 
"FOXO1_TRUNC", "GNA13_NA", "GNA13_MUTATION", "GNA13_Synon", "GNA13_TRUNC", 
"HIST1H1E_NA", "HIST1H1E_MUTATION", "HIST1H1E_Synon", "HIST1H1E_TRUNC", 
"IRF8_NA", "IRF8_MUTATION", "IRF8_Synon", "IRF8_TRUNC", "KLHL6_NA", 
"KLHL6_MUTATION", "KLHL6_Synon", "KLHL6_TRUNC", "KMT2D_NA", "KMT2D_MUTATION", 
"KMT2D_Synon", "KMT2D_TRUNC", "MEF2B_NA", "MEF2B_MUTATION", "MEF2B_Synon", 
"MEF2B_TRUNC", "MYC_NA", "MYC_MUTATION", "MYC_Synon", "MYC_TRUNC", 
"MYD88_NA", "MYD88_L265P", "MYD88_MUTATION", "MYD88_Synon", "MYD88_TRUNC", 
"PIM1_NA", "PIM1_MUTATION", "PIM1_Synon", "PIM1_TRUNC", "PRDM1_NA", 
"PRDM1_MUTATION", "PRDM1_Synon", "PRDM1_TRUNC", "RHOA_NA", "RHOA_MUTATION", 
"RHOA_TRUNC", "S1PR2_NA", "S1PR2_MUTATION", "S1PR2_Synon", "S1PR2_TRUNC", 
"SGK1_NA", "SGK1_MUTATION", "SGK1_Synon", "SGK1_TRUNC", "STAT3_MUTATION", 
"STAT3_Synon", "STAT3_TRUNC", "TNFAIP3_NA", "TNFAIP3_MUTATION", 
"TNFAIP3_Synon", "TNFAIP3_TRUNC", "TNFRSF14_NA", "TNFRSF14_MUTATION", 
"TNFRSF14_Synon", "TNFRSF14_TRUNC", "TP53_NA", "TP53_MUTATION", 
"TP53_Synon", "TP53_TRUNC", "LymphGen_call")

is.data.frame (tmp)
>> [1] TRUE

> dput(!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp)))
c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

Oddly `names(tmp)[!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp))]` works.
Using `View (tmp[,c(-list of column names generated by 'names(tmp)[!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp))])]` - works as well.

However, `View(tmp[,names(tmp)[!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp))]])`
doesn't work either

Using "!grepl" to subset 'dta' works just fine.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I think we'll need a reproducible example to help you out, i.e. a `dput(tmp)`.

Comment: Does `tmp[, !(names(tmp) %in% "Tumor_Sample_Barcode")]` make any difference?

Comment: It seems to me that the `tmp` object in the first snippet can't be the same as that in the third snippet, because the first is of type "logical", compared to type "list" for the dataframe. Therefore something in your code has changed "tmp" between those points.

Comment: Maybe add `drop=FALSE` : `tmp[, !grepl("Tumor",names(tmp)), drop=FALSE]`

Comment: `drop=FALSE` does it for `!grepl`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up recasting 'tmp' as.data.frame and it worked.
I don't fully understand why ...

```
> is.data.frame(tmp)
[1] TRUE

tmp=as.data.frame(tmp)

tmp=tmp [,!grepl("Tumor",names(tmp))]  ## this previously resulted in tmp becoming a list of logical values (see original post)

> is.data.frame(tmp)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be tied to use of `!` for negation, that was likely realized previously, as there is an `invert = TRUE` option in grep but not in grepl, your names as vector called `cancer`:

```
cancer[grep('Tumor', cancer, perl = TRUE)]
[1] "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"

cancer [!grep('Tumor', cancer, perl = TRUE)]
character(0)

cancer[grep('Tumor', cancer, invert=TRUE)]
  [1] "B2M_NA"            "B2M_MUTATION"      "B2M_Synon" ...
```

So incomplete explanation as still fishing around for !grepl implications. And the `!grepl` case and indicated by @gki:

```
cancer[!grepl('Tumor', cancer), drop = FALSE]
  [1] "B2M_NA"            "B2M_MUTATION"      "B2M_Synon" ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't resolve the issue - it seems the problem lies in trying to subset the dataframe based on a vector of logicals for columns (i.e. 

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[35]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE)

For reasons that I don't understand recasting the dataframe as.data.frame worked